# Wordpress global variables

Tags: php, wordpress, global

A while back, I remember having this nasty bug I think had to do with wordpress's global variables (when I refactored it worked fine). The variable didn't appear on the http://codex.wordpress.org/Global_Variables page, but I mostly moved on since it wasn't a big deal.

I'm working on another project now, with a blog, and am considering wordpress. I don't like this funny business with globals (come on - they reserved `page`?) But would at least like a proper reference. The page above says **Accessing other globals besides the ones listed below is not recommended.** So I assume there are other globals? Where can I find these variables, to make sure I don't clash with them?

And while I'm at it, why didn't they store those in a single, global wordpress variable >.<

Comment: Because WordPress has been hacked on by many developers over many years. Don’t look at it as an example of great code.

Comment: @MartinBean do you have recommendations for "good" blogging platform/alternatives? I've looked at Drupal and Joomla but they seem overkill for a simple blog